Use colorScheme environment value to use in a model class
I'm trying to get the Use colorScheme environment value in the view and based on the colorScheme, use a different theme model for Colors
@Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
self.themeModel.setTheme(colorScheme == .light ? LightTheme() : DarkTheme())

But I get warning
Accessing Environment's value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.
And always see colorScheme = .light
How can I do this?

Where did you put the two lines of code you showed?

As I said in the question, I'm trying to get this colorScheme in a view

Where in a view? Please show a [mcve].

@Environment properties can only be declared:

inside a View;
inside types conforming to ViewModifier and *Style; and
Property wrappers conforming to DynamicProperty.


In my experience, even trying to read environment properties inside a View.body hasn't quite worked as expected.

You have two options:

The straightforward:

Use UITraitCollection.current to acquire the current colour scheme if you are dealing with UIKit views instead; OR





The more "SwiftUI-y":

Create a separate class, conform it to ObservableObject, and add your a ColorScheme property, annotated with @Published:



final class MyObject: ObservableObject {
  @Published var colorScheme: ColorScheme
}

In your view, assign the environment value "on appear" to your object, so that it can be used outside of a SwiftUI.View:
struct MyView: View {
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
  @ObservedObject var myObject: MyObject // must be passed via init

  var body: some View {
    myViewBody
      .onAppear { 
        myObject.colorScheme = colorScheme
      }
  } 
}

As a matter of fact, you may not even need the ObservableObject/@Published/@ObservedObject if you are not planning to use MyObject inside your view.
